# Going from a parametric equation to non-parametric

Tags: linear-algebra

Having a bit of trouble going from parametric equations to non-parametic. Just not sure where to begin I guess.

Trying to find the equation of plane (in $ax + by +cz = d$) passing through $(2,0,1)$ and orthogonal to the line $x=(2,-1,3) + (1,2,-2)t$.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The normal to the plane is: $\vec{N} = (1,2,-2)$, thus the equation of the plane is: $\vec{N}\cdot (X-(2,0,1)) = 0, X = (x,y,z) \Rightarrow (1,2,-2)\cdot (x-2,y,z-1) = 0 \Rightarrow x-2+2y-2(z-1) = 0\Rightarrow x + 2y - 2z = 0$